# Nullpointerexception only in signed APK

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, searchview

I have a fragment that contains the following code:

```
SearchView searchView;

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.searchship, menu);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

        searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        searchView.setOnSearchClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    menu.findItem(R.id.action_sort).setVisible(false);

            }
        });
```

If I run this from AndroidStudio then everything is fine. But everyone who downloads the app from the playstore crashes:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.setOnSearchClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
```

Comment: Did you use ProGuard? Did you test your release version? (Also: Every app is "signed" or you could not install it)

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant, if it's obfuscated it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm sure this is always working. [https://stackoverflow.com/a/71690782/6037561](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71690782/6037561)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I found:

I have to add

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }
```

to proguard.pro

Answer (score -1):

The below code is working

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }
```

Comment: Explain it please!

Comment: I was facing a weird problem where the SearchView was used and it was working properly in the emulator and standalone apk. But when I signed the apk and uploaded in play store, users were getting a null pointer exception. After I added the above code to the proguard, it was working properly.

Comment: And how does it differ from JDoe's answer?